# Is Hamachi on a Linux production server a big system vulnerability?

Tags: webserver, vulnerability

The production server I am administrating can only be accessed through the company-network. However, if I have to do maintenance while not in the office, I can't access the server.

Could I let Hamachi run on the server and join a group? At home I join the same group and can easily access the server through SSH.

However, is this a big system vulnerability. Is it justifiable to use Hamachi for this reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is a security concern. That said it may be acceptable.

Installing any application, and certainly ones that allow remote access, does open up vulnerabilities and risks that otherwise may not have existed. But you may determine that the risk is worth accepting as it allows you to work remotely.

You can configure some security on Hamachi to restrict it to some extent, but you can not be sure of any vulnerabilities that may exist (now or in the future).

Only you know if the risk is acceptable, and only you know if installing this is allowed within corporate policies. You should be careful though you do not breech any policies.